# how can I stop an object from rotating while other parts rotate?

Tags: c++, opengl, rotation, glut, arrow-keys

I've just drawn a 3 dof robot with 3 joints which are revoloute , i've drawn a shere to use as an obstacle which should be constant without any moving but as the gripper of the robot starts to move my obstacle moves too, which shouldnt,2nd problem is : i want to turn arond my robot i did this by arrow keys theres no error but it dosent work.here is my code:

```
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define VIEW_TURN_RATE  10
#define GLUT
#define GLUT_KEY
#define GLUT_SPEC

float t1=30;
float t2=45;
float t3=45;
float t4=0;
float t5=0;
float l=1.5;
float h=0.2*l;
double m=0.2;
double n=0.2;
double p=0.2;

float eyex,eyey=0;
float eyez=6;
float lx,ly,lz=0;

int turn = 0, turn1 = 0;

void TurnRight(void)
{
    turn = (turn - VIEW_TURN_RATE) % 360;
}

void TurnLeft(void)
{
    turn = (turn + VIEW_TURN_RATE) % 360;
}

void TurnForwards(void)
{
    turn1 = (turn1 - VIEW_TURN_RATE) % 360;
}

void TurnBackwards(void)
{
    turn1 = (turn1 + VIEW_TURN_RATE) % 360;
}

void myidlefunc()
{
    if(t1<100)
        t1+=2;
    else
    {   
        if(t2<150)
            t2+=2;
        else
        {

            if(t3<150)
                t3+=2;
            else
            {

                if(t4<150)
                    t4+=2;
                else
                {

                    if(t5<120)
                        t5+=2;
                    else
                    {
                        glutIdleFunc(0);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    glutPostRedisplay();
}

#ifdef GLUT
#ifdef GLUT_SPEC
void
    special(int key, int x, int y)
{

    int i = 0;
    printf("this is special keyboard: %d \n",key);
    switch (key) {
        /* start of view position functions */
    case 'r':{
        TurnRight();
        i++;
             }
             break;
    case GLUT_KEY_LEFT:{
        TurnLeft();
        i++;
                       }
                       break;
    case GLUT_KEY_DOWN:{
        TurnForwards();
        i++;
                       }
                       break;
    case GLUT_KEY_UP:{
        TurnBackwards();
        i++;
                     }
                     break;
                     /* end of view postions functions */
    }
    if (i)
        glutPostRedisplay();
}
#endif

#ifdef GLUT_KEY
void keyboard(unsigned char c,int x,int y)
{
    switch(c)
    {
    case 27:
        exit(0);
        break;

    case 's':
        if (t1 < 50) {
            t1++;}
        break;
    case 'S':
        //if (t1 < 80) {
        t1--;
        //}
        break;
    case 'q':
        glutIdleFunc(myidlefunc);
        break;
    case 'f':
        if (t2 < 160) {
            t2++;}
        break;
    case 'F':
        t2--;
        break;
    case 'g':
        t3++;
        break;
    case 'h':
        t4++;
        break;
    case 'k':
        t5++;
        break;
    }
    glutPostRedisplay();
}
#endif
#endif

void drawFloor(void)
{
    glPushMatrix ();
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glColor3f(0.0,0.8,0.8);
    glVertex3f(-20.0, 0.0, 100.0);
    glVertex3f(20.0, 0.0, 100.0);
    glVertex3f(20.0, 0.0, -100.0);
    glVertex3f(-20.0, 0.0, -100.0);
    glEnd();
    glPopMatrix ();
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
}

void Base(float l)
{
    glPushMatrix();
    //glColor3f(0.4,0.6,0.5);
    glScaled(1.0*l,0.2*l,1.0*l);
    glutSolidCube(1);
    glPopMatrix();
}

void obst(float radius, int slices, int stacks)
{
    glTranslated (0,-0.5,0.0);
    glPushMatrix ();
    glutSolidSphere (radius,slices,stacks);
    glPopMatrix ();
}

void arm(float l,float r,int slices,int stacks,float rotat)
{
    float d;
    d=0.2*l;

    glTranslated (0,l/2+d/2,0);
    glPushMatrix ();
    glScaled (d/l,1,d/l);
    glutSolidCube (l);
    glPopMatrix ();

    glTranslated (0,l/2,0);
    glRotated (rotat,0,0,1);
    glPushMatrix ();
    glutSolidSphere (r,slices,stacks);
    glPopMatrix ();
}

void Base2(float l,float r,int slices,int stacks,float rotat)
{
    float d;
    d=0.2*l;

    glTranslated (d/2,d/2,d/2);
    glPushMatrix ();
    glScaled (d,d/2,d);
    glutSolidCube (2);
    glPopMatrix ();
}

void hand(float d,float x)
{
    glColor3f(0.0,0.4,0.3);
    glRotated(t5,0,1,0);
    glPushMatrix ();
    glTranslated(0,-d/2+x/2,0);
    glScaled(1,x/d,1);
    glutSolidCube (d);
    glPopMatrix();

    glPushMatrix ();
    glTranslated(-d/2+x/2,x/2,0);
    glScaled (x/(d-x),1,d/(d-x));
    glutSolidCube(d-x);
    glPopMatrix ();

    glPushMatrix ();
    glTranslated (d/2-x/2,x/2,0);
    glScaled (x/(d-x),1,d/(d-x));
    glutSolidCube(d-x);
    glPopMatrix ();
}

void display()
{
    float l,T,r,x,d;
    double radius,height;
    int slices, stacks;
    l=1.5;
    T=30;
    d=0.2*l;
    x=0.2*d;
    r=d/2;
    radius=1.0;
    height=3;
    slices=1000;
    stacks=202;

    glClearColor(1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0);
    glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glPushMatrix ();
    //lightning start here
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
    GLfloat light0_pos []={lx,ly+1,lz+1,1};
    GLfloat light0_diffuse []={1,0,0,0};
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0,GL_DIFFUSE,light0_diffuse);

    GLfloat light0_Ambient []={0,1,1,0};
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0,GL_DIFFUSE,light0_Ambient);

    gluLookAt(0.2,0.8,0.0,5.0,3.0,5.0,0.0,0.1,0.0);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0,GL_POSITION,light0_pos);

    glScaled(0.2,0.2,0.2);
    glRotated(90,0.0,1.0,0.0);



    /* Draw "bottom" of floor in blue. */
    glColor3f(0.0, 0.8, 0.8);
    drawFloor();

    //base
    glColor3f(0.0,0.0,0.0);
    Base(2);

    //base2
    glColor3f(1.0,0.0,0.0);
    Base2(l,r,60,60,t1);

    //arm1  

    glColor3f(1.0,0.0,0.8);
    arm(l,r,60,60,t1);

    glColor3f(0.0,1.0,0.0);
    arm(l,r,60,60,t2);

    glColor3f(1.0,0.8,0.5);
    arm(l,r,60,60,t3);


    //hand   
    glTranslated (0,d/2+r,0);
    hand(d,x);

    //obst
    glTranslated (-1,3,0);
    glColor3f(0.0,0.0,1.0);
    obst(radius,slices,stacks);
    //glRotated(0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0);

    glPopMatrix ();
    glFlush();
    glutSwapBuffers();  
}

void reshape(int width,int height)
{
    float aspect=(float)width/(float)height;
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glViewport(0,0,width,height);

    //glOrtho(-aspect,aspect,-1,+1,-1,+1);
    gluPerspective(60.0,0.0,0.0,8);

    glMatrixMode (GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    //glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);  /* viewing transform  */
}

int main(int argc,char** argv)
{ 
    glutInit(&argc,argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA|GLUT_DOUBLE);
    glutInitWindowPosition(0,0);
    glutInitWindowSize(500,500);
    static int window=glutCreateWindow("OPenGL!");
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
    glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard);
#ifdef GLUT_SPEC
    glutSpecialFunc(special);
#endif

    glShadeModel(GL_FLAT);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
    glutMainLoop();
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Just a comment on coding style, you can express your nested if-else statements in a more readable format (forgive the lack of new-lines in a comment) as: `if(t1<100)
 t1+=2;
else if(t2<150)
 t2+=2;
else if(t3<150)
 t3+=2;
else if(t4<150)
 t4+=2;
else if(t5<120)
 t5+=2;
else
 glutIdleFunc(0);`

Answer (score 1):

As you are rendering the obstacle last, your modelview matrix has been the recipient of all the transforms up to that point. You need to manage your modelview matrix more carefully using `glPushMatrix()` and `glPopMatrix()`. I haven't tested but try a push just before `//arm 1` and pop just before your `//obst`.

Comment: Dear Edf your idea worked tnx so much. do you have any idea about my second question ?

Comment: Regarding your other question, you can check for a collision with the knowledge of your positions and sizes of the parts of your system. This knowledge is currently spread throughout your graphical functions. It could be worth consolidating it into objects and then using them for both the graphical and collision detection algorithms.